# how to pass parameters to Handlebars helper? What's the difference between options.hash & options.data

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Here's a typical Handlebars helper:

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper 'myHelper', (value, options) ->
  ...
```

According to [this protip](https://coderwall.com/p/bs67zw) you can pass hash to Handlebars helpers. I looked over the source and found out that it provides both `options.hash` and `options.data`. I'm a bit confused as this wouldn't work as expected:

```
{{#with controllers.currentCardCategory}}
  {{#each property in cardProperties}}
    <td class="td">{{cardProperty this property=property.symbol}}</td> 
  {{/each}}
{{/with}}
```

`this` is the current `Card` record. Here I got `property.symbol` as string

But this worked:

```
{{#with controllers.currentCardCategory}}
  {{#each property in cardProperties}}
    <td class="td">{{cardProperty this property.symbol}}</td> 
  {{/each}}
{{/with}}
```

and the value was accessible via `options`.

But now I can't do this:

```
{{#with controllers.currentCardCategory}}
  {{#each property in cardProperties}}
    <td class="td">{{cardProperty this property.symbol anotherParam yetAnotherParam}}</td> 
  {{/each}}
{{/with}}
```

My question is: **how to pass other parameters to the helper** and **what's the difference between `options.hash` and `options.data` in the helper**?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Parameters passed to a helper become `arguments` to the helper function. The values you provide in the template immediately after the `{{helperName` become the arguments. The last argument passed to the helper is an `options` object that provides additional information to helper like, an `options.hash` and `options.contexts`, etc. Key value pairs provided after the parameters correspond to the `options.hash` property.

For a `hello` helper that takes 3 arguments, the helper would be,

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('hello', function(a, b, c, options) {
  return '%@ - %@ - %@'.fmt(a, b, c);
});
```

The `hello` helper can be used in a template like so,

```
{{hello lorem ipsum dolor}}
```

Here the values of `lorem`, `ipsum`, and `dolor` properties would be used and returned as a combined string.

In addition to the required arguments, if you pass in additonal parameters they would be available in `options.hash`. These properties are treated as strings and aren't resolved by default. You would need to use, `options.data.view` to lookup their values first. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17532878/calling-a-handlebars-block-helper-from-another-helper/17540118#17540118) for an example if you need to do this.

Finally `options.data` is special property provided to helpers. It's the raw handlebars `Frame` that holds variables, contexts and so on. It is mostly for use with block helpers. Since block helpers don't do rendering themselves but call other helpers, `options.data` allows such block helpers to inject additional variables into the child helpers frame. For details see the docs [here](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/block-helpers.html).

Here's a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/uxakic/1/edit) example.