# Handlebars custom helper argument not working properly

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I am passing variable in handlebars custom helper "{{renderHTML model.content}} "

but in helper argument It is coming just as string '**model.content**'

Comment: Example is here http://jsfiddle.net/Yh8WA/

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to pass parameters to Handlebars helper? What's the difference between options.hash & options.data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17954192/how-to-pass-parameters-to-handlebars-helper-whats-the-difference-between-optio)

Comment: what u want as the expected output ?

Comment: If you trying to embed html string as is in Handlebars template, please use [triple mustache](http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html). Your updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Yh8WA/1/

Answer (score 1):

You should use Ember.Handlebars.**registerBoundHelper** not Em.Handlebars.**registerHelper**